# Is it correct to say "We will provide you with the best consultation and assist you filling out..."

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Would a phrase like the following be correct?

> We will provide you with the best consultation and assist you filling out...

or would I need to include a preposition to be proper:

> We will provide you with the best consultation and assist you ***in*** filling out...

Comment: [*Assist you in*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assist+you+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cassist%20you%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bassist%20you%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bassist%20you%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bassist%20you%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bassist%20you%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bassist%20you%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bassist%20you%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bassist%20you%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bassist%20you%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bassist%20you%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bassist%20you%20when%3B%2Cc0) is a common expression, but the omission does no harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the preposition you need is "in"

*assist you **in** filling out..*

I don't really like the beginning of the phrase, spelling mistake aside. The adjective "best" does not sound good here.

I might change the sentence to read:

*We provide an excellent consultation service and will assist you in filling out....*

Comment: _with_ is also often used, although Google Ngram shows that _in_ is far more common.

Answer (score 1):

A change in word usage might help.  Because you are already "providing" a consultation...

> We will provide you with the best consultation and [additional] assistance in filling out...

The use of an adjective like "additional" is at your discretion depending on the context.  However, the use of "in" seems fairly necessary for clarity.